# How to pass information from Node to React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an object i need to parse to React.
I'm trying to get the "rows" object (in the node function) over to a React State. 
The 2 piece of code below are on different pages!

The other issue is 
 GET http://localhost:3000/new net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I am currently running these both locally 
React  http://localhost:3001/
Node - http://localhost:3000/

There have been SIMILAR questions to this but I can't find an answer with both issues!
Thanks

```
router.get("/new", (req, res) => {
let parentList = sql.fetchAllParents(function(err, rows) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3001");
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render('new', {parents: rows});
  });
});

componentDidMount() {
   fetch(`http://localhost:3000/new`).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      return response.json();
   }).then(data => {
      // Work with JSON data here
      console.log(data,'data');
   }).catch(err => {
      // Do something for an error here
      console.log("Error Reading data " + err);
   });
}
```

Comment: you can use proxy in package json. so whenever a request happens in react when we add the proxy in package.json it will route to the different port.

Comment: and here is the link mentioned on the comment above: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

Answer (score 1):

Send response from node "new" api. Like this:

```
router.get("/new", (req, res) => {
......
......
res.send({status:200,parents:data})
```

});

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't seem to work?!
React just wont read it